# Create an object from the contents of a variable java

Tags: java

How do I Create an object from the contents of a variable in Java?

For example: if the string variable  "name" has a value of "Margaret"

and I apply this constructor

```
Name nx= new Name();
```

I want Java to know that I´m refering to the content of name. Therefore Java will know that I'm refering to Margaret

What I want is to create Dynamic objects without the name fixed.

I can do this in PHP but I'm new in Java and don't know if is it possible.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a class called Name? What does it look like?

Comment: How are you doing this in PHP? (just to make it clearer what you're trying to do)

Comment: Perhaps you want to check `Class.forName`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-

Comment: Diego Basch I have a class Called Margaret.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic instantiation of Java classes is far more complicated than doing the same thing in PHP. In PHP you'd just use eval(), i guess.

You can get an instance of the `Class` object by using [Class.forName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader)). Afterwards, you would have to instantiate the object by using the [Class.newInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()):

```
Class cls = Class.forName(name);
Object obj = cls.newInstance();
```

This is the simplest case. If the constructor needs parameters, you would have to get the constructor method and call it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try with "forName"